# iOS Development Testing Requirements

Tags: ios, iphone

On [Apple's website](https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/) they say you to test on `iPad, iPhone and iPod touch`.
Is it actually required to test on all three before distributing the app, or is it acceptable to just test on one of them (say, iPhone)?

Comment: Test on every single physical device you own, then test on all of your friends and families iDevices (if possible), and test on every single different iOS simulator that you support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

is not required,or rather, they may not know where you've tested the app, but it is obviously highly recommended to test the app on all devices and all iOS supported by your app.

the simulator replaces a device well true, but sometimes it can happen to encounter errors that simply can not be seen on the simulator, but that may be encountered on a real device

To avoid unexpected problems is always better to try more devices